# Refined list sorting by substring integer after alphabetical sorting

Tags: vb.net, list

I have some information in a list (called listLines). Each line below is in a List(Of String).

```
1|This is just a header
3|This is just a footer
2|3456789|0000000|12312312313|BLUE|1|35.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645655|BLUE|1|22.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645658|RED|2|13.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312316|RED|2|45.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312317|YELLOW|5|-9.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312315|ORANGE|3|15.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645659|YELLOW|5|32.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312314|GREEN|4|-20.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645656|GREEN|4|39.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645657|ORANGE|3|-18.50
```

I'm doing a `listLines.sort()` on the list to sort it alphabetically. Below is what I get after the `.sort()`.

```
1|This is just a header
2|3456789|0000000|12312312313|BLUE|1|35.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312314|GREEN|4|-20.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312315|ORANGE|3|15.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312316|RED|2|45.00
2|3456789|0000000|12312312317|YELLOW|5|-9.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645655|BLUE|1|22.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645656|GREEN|4|39.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645657|ORANGE|3|-18.50
2|7891230|0000000|45645645658|RED|2|13.00
2|7891230|0000000|45645645659|YELLOW|5|32.00
3|This is just a footer
```

With that said, I need to output this information to a file. I'm able to do this ok. I still have a problem though. There is a sequence number in the above data at position 5 just after the listed colors (RED, BLUE, ETC..) that you can see. It's just before the last value which is a decimal type.

I need to further sort this list, keeping it in alphabetical order since position 2 is an account number and I want to keep the account numbers grouped together. I just want them to be resorted in sequential order based on the sequence number.

I was looking at another thread trying to figure out how I can do this. I found a piece of code like `listLines.OrderBy(Function(q) q.Substring(35)).ToArray`. I think this would probably help me if this was a fixed length file, it isn't however. I was thinking I can do some kind of `.split()` to get the 5th piece of information and sort it but then it's going to unalphabetize and mix the lines back up because I don't know how to specify to still keep it alphabetical.

Right now I'm outputting my alphabetical list like below so I can format it with commas and double quotes.

```
    For Each listLine As String In listLines
        strPosition = Split(listLine, "|")
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Dim iBound As Integer = UBound(strPosition)
        Do While (i <= iBound)
            strOutputText = strOutputText & Chr(34) & strPosition(i) & Chr(34) & ","
            i += 1
        Loop
```

My main question is how do I re-sort after .sort() to then get each account (position1) in sequential order (position 5)? OR EVEN BETTER, how can I do both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List(Of T)` class has an overload of the `Sort` method that takes a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate. I would suggest that you use that. It allows you to write a method or lambda expression that will take two items and compare them any way you want. In this case, you could do that like this:

```vb
Dim items = New List(Of String) From {"1|This Is just a header",
                                      "3|This Is just a footer",
                                      "2|3456789|0000000|12312312313|BLUE|1|35.00",
                                      "2|7891230|0000000|45645645655|BLUE|1|22.00",
                                      "2|7891230|0000000|45645645658|RED|2|13.00",
                                      "2|3456789|0000000|12312312316|RED|2|45.00",
                                      "2|3456789|0000000|12312312317|YELLOW|5|-9.00",
                                      "2|3456789|0000000|12312312315|ORANGE|3|15.00",
                                      "2|7891230|0000000|45645645659|YELLOW|5|32.00",
                                      "2|3456789|0000000|12312312314|GREEN|4|-20.00",
                                      "2|7891230|0000000|45645645656|GREEN|4|39.00",
                                      "2|7891230|0000000|45645645657|ORANGE|3|-18.50"}

items.Sort(Function(x, y)
               Dim xParts = x.Split("|"c)
               Dim yParts = y.Split("|"c)

               'Compare by the first column first.
               Dim result = xParts(0).CompareTo(yParts(0))

               If result = 0 Then
                   'Compare by the second column next.
                   result = xParts(1).CompareTo(yParts(1))
               End If

               If result = 0 Then
                   'Compare by the sixth column last.
                   result = xParts(5).CompareTo(yParts(5))
               End If

               Return result
           End Function)

For Each item In items
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

If you prefer a named method then do this:

```vb
Private Function CompareItems(x As String, y As String) As Integer
    Dim xParts = x.Split("|"c)
    Dim yParts = y.Split("|"c)

    'Compare by the first column first.
    Dim result = xParts(0).CompareTo(yParts(0))

    If result = 0 Then
        'Compare by the second column next.
        result = xParts(1).CompareTo(yParts(1))
    End If

    If result = 0 Then
        'Compare by the sixth column last.
        result = xParts(5).CompareTo(yParts(5))
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

and this:

```vb
items.Sort(AddressOf CompareItems)
```

Just note that this is rather inefficient because it splits both items on each comparison. That's not a big deal for a small list but, if there were a lot of items, it would be better to split each item once and then sort based on those results.

Comment: Looks like this is a good method thank you. 

What does the "c" do in x.Split("|"c)?

Comment: @shadow2020, that is a `Char` literal. If you have `Option Strict On`, which you always should, then you cannot pass a `String` literal where a `Char` is expected and rely on the system to implicitly convert it for you.

Comment: One other question, I don't fully understand how this is sorting. I get that we are using campareto and comparing two object of the same type but I don't understand exactly how that help to sort things around. Is there more happening under the hood?

Comment: @shadow2020, all sorting is done by comparing two items at a time and deciding what to do with them based on the result. The individual algorithm determines what sequence to compare items in and what to do with them after the comparison, but not the comparison itself. What constitutes "less than" and "greater than" depends on the items being sorted and the criteria you want them sorted by. .NET uses the QuickSort algorithm, if I'm not mistaken, so the `List(Of T).Sort` method knows which items to compare and what to do with them but not how to compare them.

Comment: @shadow2020, if the items implement the `IComparable` interface then the default comparison implementation of the items themselves can be used. That's not always what you want though, e.g. you might want to sort `Strings` by `Length` rather than alphabetically. If the items don't provide their own comparison implementation then you have no choice but to provide one yourself. In this case, we provide a method that will compare two items and return a value indicating their relative size and then the `Sort` method calls that internally each time it compares two items.

Comment: @shadow2020, you may benefit from reading all three parts of [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html) blog post of mine.